# Values disappear from table when select

Tags: python, pandas

I have table which contains a lot of data about plants from different dates. 
I am trying to select all the data from specific date, but anytime I do that all the data disappear and I get table that has only the columns names.

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline

df_plants = pd.read_csv('Data_plants_26_11_2019.csv')
df_Nit=pd.read_csv('chemometrics.csv')

df_plants.head()

#create new colum which contains aonly the hour using lambda
df_plants['Hour']=df_plants['time'].apply(lambda time: time.split(' ')[1])
df_plants['date']=df_plants['time'].apply(lambda time: time.split(' ')[0])


df_plants['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df_plants['Hour']).apply(lambda x: str(x.hour) + ':00')

df_indices=df_plants[['plant','date','Hour','Treatment','Line','NDVI','YU_index','Zhao 405-715']]

df_indices[df_indices['date']==6/22/2019]
```

The results:

[image]

this is how the table looks if I use head() before I try to get only specific dates:

[image]

My end goal is to  get new table which contains ONLY the values from a specific date I choose

Comment: Is the columnd ['date'] a datetime object?

Comment: This comparison `df_indices[df_indices['date']==6/22/2019]` is wrong. `6/22/2019` evaluates to `0.00013508037282182898` which obviously is not equal to the any date. Please check the dataype of `date` column by printing the output of `df_indices['date'].dtypes`

Comment: so how can I select dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue seems to be that you are performing an operation with the argument you are setting the equal to, hence Python/pandas is interpeting as a number and not a date.

You should use the value between `' '` apostrophes, like this:

```
df_indices[df_indices['date']=='6/22/2019']
```

Or in a more complex case (pandas 0.19 and above):

```
df_indices[df_indices['date'] == pd.Timestamp(year=2019,month=6,day=22).dt.date]
```

Comment: `pd.datetime(2019,6,22).date()` is a simpler option than `Timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
# first create a datetime column with the date 
# (probably you should make some changes here because of your 
# datetime format)
df_indices['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_indices['date'])
# then use pd.to_datetime() method
df_indices[df_indices['date']==pd.to_datetime('2019-06-22')]
```